# I am using LSTM for image classification. I am getting an error like this. How to avoid it?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-adadcac4df3b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_gen, epochs=10, validation_data=val_gen)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 235, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

If I add dropout layer will the error be resolved?

Comment: LSTMs are sequence models, Images are not sequences, think about it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't use LSTM for image classification, use CNN instead.